# Generate a text file of 65,535 bytes in length

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql TEXT field and I want to visually see how large 65,535 bytes is as text. What is the best way to do this?

I might need to change the field to MEDIUM TEXT or LONG TEXT. What are the tradeoffs of going bigger? Can I migrate the column easily without data loss?

I am using the field for session data management. (Serialized php code)

Comment: go to http://www.lipsum.com/ type 65535 in to the box and select bytes, click generate

Comment: I was googling around and couldn't find a byte generator. Thanks @Dagon

Comment: Hint: it's quite a lot

Comment: 64 kB is somewhere around 20 to 30 pages of printed text.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `varchar(65535)` to declare the field.

To fill it with data, I think you can do:

```
 select repeat(cast('a' as varchar(65535)), 65535)
```

Then save the results into a file.

You could also do this in some applications.  For instance, in emacs, you could open up a file and type " 6 5 5 3 5 3 a" and that would fill the buffer with lots of a's.

Comment: Do you also think I should migrate to MEDIUM or LONG text for session data storage or will that cause problems?

Comment: why are you storing session data in a single db field in the first place ?

Comment: I am using codeinigter and a load balancer and that is the method they have chosen to go with their session library. It would be hard to use php sessions with a load balancer